# CentOS 8 KVM under CentOS 7 -- Kickstart Network Install Fails

Tags: kvm-virtualization, kickstart, centos8

We have CentOS 8 KVM running under CentOS 7.  Everything seems to be working well for us once the KVM is up and running.  We are using kickstart to bootstrap the KVM.  We are having problems automating the network install sequence.

Each time we perform a virt-install, we need to fill in the "Installation source" and "Software selection" of the Installation menu manually.  When we do this, everything proceeds normally.

If we add the following two records to our kickstart,

```
# network installation -- minimal content    
url --url="http://our-server/rhel8-install"    
repo --name="Minimal" --baseurl=http://our-server/rhel8-install/Minimal
```

the install sequence fails just before the manual installation menu is displayed. The records above are copied from anaconda-ks.cfg of a successful network installation -- specified manually through the Installation menu.

We are using the latest version of CentOS 7 & 8 available.  Is this a defect or are we doing something wrong?

Here are the errors from the Installer:

```
Starting installer, one moment...
anaconda 29.19.2.17-1.el8 for CentOS Linux 8 started.
 * installation log files are stored in /tmp during the installation
 * shell is available on TTY2
 * if the graphical installation interface fails to start, try again with the
   inst.text bootoption to start text installation
 * when reporting a bug add logs from /tmp as separate text/plain attachments
16:04:26 Not asking for VNC because of an automated install
16:04:26 Not asking for VNC because text mode was explicitly asked for in kickstart







  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyanaconda/anaconda.py", line 394, in initInterfac initInterface
    self._intf = TextUserInterface(self.storage, self.payload,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyanaconda/anaconda.py", line 199, in storage
    self._set_default_fstype(self._storage)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyanaconda/anaconda.py", line 310, in _set_default_fstype
    storage.set_default_fstype(fstype)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/blivet/threads.py", line 53, in run_with_lock
    return m(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/blivet/blivet.py", line 1070, in set_default_fstype
    self._check_valid_fstype(newtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/blivet/threads.py", line 53, in run_with_lock
    return m(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/blivet/blivet.py", line 1055, in _check_valid_fstyp
    raise ValueError("new value %s is not valid as a default fs type" % newtype)





ValueError: new value xfs is not valid as a default fs type

Pane is dead (status 1, Wed Jun 24 16:04:26 2020)
```

Comment: Well, that's an odd one. Especially since some of it seems to be missing. Check in the `/tmp` directory and see if a more complete message was logged somewhere.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this KVM never completed the Install process.  I'm not sure I can check the /tmp directory as the KVM was never created.

Comment: Do you mean the VM? You typed KVM. And yes, if the installation failed, then logs in `/tmp` are expected, just as the on screen text says.

Comment: Yes -- this is a VM created with virt-install.  I looked at the DOM0 /tmp directory -- nothing there as I expected.  I do not know how to access the VM /tmp directory -- the console is no longer available and I do not know how to access the VM.

Comment: It's just a tmux, so you use regular tmux commands to switch shells, or you can just switch virtual consoles.

Comment: I can not gain access to the console. I issued "virsh console VM_Name" from DOM0.  This resulted in "error: operation failed: Active console session exists for this domain".